# Is there an efficient algorithm to find all intersecting polygons?

Tags: algorithm, polygon

I have two sets of polygons. Red polygons and blue polygons, in cartesian space. I need to find all red polygons that intersect with any blue polygons. I am currently using a simple double-for loop approach to solve this. Here is the pseudocode:

```
var candidates = HashMap<Int, Polygon>();
for (var red : redPolygons) {
    for (var blue : bluePolygons) {
        if (polygonsIntersect(red, blue)) {
           candidates[red.id] = red.polygon;
           break;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm looking for a more efficient algorithm. Ideally something better than O(N^2).

Some more details. The number of blue polygons is typically small (less than 100), and dynamic. The number of red polygons is large, and does not change often, so preprocessing the red polygons is a viable option.

Comment: Indeed your algorithm is not N^2. Because the intersection could be done in `log(M)` in terms of the size of the polygon. So it is `N^2 log(M)` (M is the maximum size of a polygon in the union of two data sets).

Comment: Good point, though for my application the number of points in any given polygon is typically small.

Comment: Intersect bounding-boxes first?

Comment: Your pseudo-code maps `red.id`s to `red.polygon` without even mentioning the intersecting blue one: what is the idea?

Comment: Push the red polygons (or its bounding boxes) into a quadtree or a kdtree. Then, for every blue polygon, you will be able to get the subset of all the red polygons that may intersect it.

Answer (score 0):

> Ideally something better than O(N^2)

(note that there may be O(N²) intersections: many an advanced algorithm below uses a lot of time worst case.)
Many problems in *computational geometry* is simpler if all edges are parallel to one of the axes (iso-oriented); many *polygon problems* are simpler if "all" polygons are convex.

If you are looking for polygons with intersecting edges, only, look for
*Balaban, I. J.* (1995): "An optimal algorithm for finding segments intersections".
 For the special case of intersections between two sets of edges/polygons, there are
*Chan, T. M.* (1994): "A Simple Trapezoid Sweep Algorithm for Reporting Red/Blue Segment Intersections",
*Mantler, A.; Snoeyink, J.* (2001): "Intersecting Red and Blue Line Segments in Optimal Time and Precision",
*Basch, J.; Guibas, L. J.; Ramkumar, G. D.* (2003) "Reporting Red-Blue Intersections between Two Sets of Connected Line Segments", …

If you need containment, too (polygon overlap), it is enough to pick *one* point from each polygon and check for containment in any polygon from "the other set"; it should be possible to do intersection and containment checking in a single [line sweep](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm).

> preprocessing the red polygons is a viable option.

The conventional preprocessing includes ordering the vertices by coordinate.

Comment: (The CS approach to solving "overlap" is declaring it solved by *intersection* and *point containment*.)